# MySQL RegExp Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid'

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to make a consult in MySQL of telephone numbers, that don't start with '33' and 10 characters long, I try with:

```
^(?!33)[0-9]{10}$
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT calldate, src, dst, billsec, disposition, accountcode FROM cdr WHERE (calldate BETWEEN @inicio AND @fin) AND CHAR_LENGTH(src) = 4 AND disposition LIKE 'ANSWERED' AND billsec >= 1 AND  dst RLIKE '^(?!33)[0-9]{10}$';
```

But don't work on MySQL, but work in sublime text 3. I got the error:

```
ERROR 1139 (42000): Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

How can I use a regex in MySQL that macht with that pattern.

Comment: MySQL regular expressions don't have lookarounds. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html for the documentation of MySQL regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> MySQL uses Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions,
>   which is aimed at conformance with POSIX 1003.2. MySQL uses the
>   extended version to support pattern-matching operations performed with
>   the REGEXP operator in SQL statements.

Lookaheads aren't available with POSIX regex. The best solution may be to put another clause in the select statement:

```
SELECT  calldate, src, dst, billsec, disposition, accountcode
    FROM  cdr
    WHERE  (calldate BETWEEN @inicio AND @fin)
      AND  CHAR_LENGTH(src) = 4
      AND  disposition LIKE 'ANSWERED'
      AND  billsec >= 1
      AND  dst RLIKE '^[0-9]{10}$'
      AND  dst NOT RLIKE '^33'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the negative lookahead: `^[0-9]{10}$`

Just use another statement to avoid things that start with `33`: `AND dst NOT LIKE '33%'`.

It's probably faster to do it like this, too.